# Multiple dummy iframes not working

Tags: html, iframe

I have specified `iframe` in closing tag but I only see the first one.
Below is my code.

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="iframe2" id="iframe2"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change height , width
like in

```
<iframe width="10" height="10" border="10" name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe width="100" height="10" border="10" name="iframe2" id="iframe2"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="AlertMaintenance" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="AlertMaintenance.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="DelayReason" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="DelayReason.html"></iframe>
```